# C# Sample to use DynamicTemplates with NEST and ElasticSearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

Actually Nest has the option to configure Dynamic Mapping with this mapping (taken from NEST Source code)

```
.DynamicTemplates(d => d
                .Add(t => t
                    .Name("template_1")
                    .Match("multi*")
                    .Mapping(tm => tm
                        .MultiField(mf => mf
                            .Fields(mff => mff
                                .Generic(g => g
                                    .Name("{name}")
                                    .Type("{dynamic_type}")
                                    .Index("analyzed")
                                    .Store(false)
```

I'd like to know if there is some option about usage with dynamic objects or dictionaries, thanks.

Gian Maria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to this [link](https://www.elastic.co/blog/managing-relations-inside-elasticsearch) to check how Elasticsearch manages relationships between objects.

Now supouse you have a Collection *MyDict* of objects in your Class:

```
public class MyClass
{   
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, object> MyDict { get; set; }
}
```

A representation of a document, instance of this class, should look like this on the index (In my example I use the MyDict collection to describe users privileges):

```
{
    "_index": "myindex",
    "_type": "myclass",
    "_id": "deb087c7d351-144b32bd-8534-4412-abbd",
    "_version": 1,
    "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
         "id": "deb087c7d351-144b32bd-8534-4412-abbd",
         "created ": "2015-07-15T12:42:00",
            "mydict": {
             "owner": "administrator",
             "permission": "777",
             "description": "superuser",
            },
        }
}
```

Now, if you want to define a DynamicTemplate that match your fields on MyDict Collection, you can use the `PathMatch` option of the template definition, this allows to match the dynamic template against the "full" dot notation name of the field [(check full documentation)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-root-object-type.html)

This is an example of DynamicTemplate for fields in MyDict Collection set to not_analyzed:

```
.DynamicTemplates(dt => dt
        .Add(t => t
            .Name("mydict_notanalyzed")
            .PathMatch("mydict.*")
            .Mapping(tm => tm
                .Generic(g => g.Index("not_analyzed")))
    )
)
```